# What does "@" do in "shellescape(@%, 1)" in Vim?

Tags: vim

In this command, what does the "@" symbol do?

`:exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)`

If I remove it, Vim says:

```
E15: Invalid expression: %, 1) 
E116: Invalid arguments for function shellescape(%, 1)
E15: Invalid expression: shellescape(%, 1)
```

---

**Edit:**

In response to:

> It’s the content of the % register (the current filename).

When I enter  `:h@`, the help file says:

> @{0-9a-z".=*+}
>
> Execute the contents of register {0-9a-z".=*+} [...]. **Note that register '%' (name of the current file) [...] cannot be used.**

These two quotes seem inconsistent, and the `shellescape` behavior seems consistent with the former quote.

**New observation:**

The following seem equivalent:

`:exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)`

`:exec '!python %'`

`:!python %`

Comment: It’s the content of the `%` register (the current filename).

Comment: :h@ says "Note that register '%' (name of the current file) [...] cannot be used."

Comment: That’s for the `@` *operator*, which is not what’s being used here; read `:h @r` instead, as mentioned in the duplicate.